Android Studio Image picker is not launching
I am using Pixel 8, API 34 Android 14
I have created a data collection form and one of the icone is pick image. When I click on the image, the image picker is not launching. It works on the older version of my app but currently I am upgrading the app to new Android version 14.
Here are some codes form AndroidManifest.xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="gov.cdc.epiinfo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

Some Codes for MainActivity.java files
@Override
public void openOptionsMenu() // Method to open the options menu, adjusting the screen layout size for large screens.
{
Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
    if ((config.screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) > Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE)
    {
        int originalScreenLayout = config.screenLayout;
        config.screenLayout = Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
        super.openOptionsMenu();
        config.screenLayout = originalScreenLayout;
    }
    else
    {
        super.openOptionsMenu();
    }
}

private boolean checkPermissions() // Method to check if necessary permissions have been granted.
{
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        Intent permissions = new Intent(this, Permissions.class);
        permissions.putExtra("PermissionType",Permissions.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES);

        //MainActivity.super.getActivityResultRegistry().onLaunch(Permissions.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES, temp, permissions, null);
        //startActivityForResult(permissions,Permissions.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES);
        permissionsActivityResultLauncher.launch(permissions);
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

Some one please help me, I highly appreciated....
This is image control
